# JQuery Post with Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Post URL is

```
/api/private/hotel?id=1
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('input.submit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#hotel-form').getFormByName();


        var url = '/api/private/hotel?id=' + id ;

        console.log(url);

        AJAXnotification("Saving...", 'info');
        $.post( url , form)
        .done(function(){
            AJAXnotification("Rooms Saved", 'success', 5000); 
        })
        .fail(function(){
            AJAXnotification("Cannot save rooms", 'error');
        })
    });
```

But I found this when i click the submit button

**Error**

> POST /api/private/hotel?id=1 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I am using $.post() function

Comment: Have you tried a full url? `var url = 'http://domain.tld/api/private/hotel?id=' + id ;`

Comment: I've mixed a query string (get) with a post before and not had a problem, but that wasn't in jquery.

Comment: it working in postman bro

Comment: Try using fiddler to see what is going over the wire. Use the composer to modify the message until it works... Perhaps the problem is in how the rest API reads the body of the message, I think this can be done in value pair (I think this is what your code does) or Jason.. I hope this helps...

Comment: no bro @TecBrat i use /api/private/hotel?id=

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL of the page (view) from where you are making ajax call.
Let say for instance it is `http://localhost:8085/MyController/MyView`

Now from Javascript you are making ajax call to one of the api `api/private/hotel`

When you do so request will be actually sent to `http://localhost:8085/MyController/api/private/hotel`

**Solution**
either you have to put exact url like `http://localhost:8085/api/private/hotel` or put URL as `../api/private/hotel`

Hope it helped